# Selenium TestNG parallel execution using mvn command

Tags: java, maven, selenium, testng

While trying to run the mvn test with profile as browser capablities, when trying to call:

```
mvn -PChrome ..... test &
mvn -PFirefox ..... test &
```

Even though they are seperate maven test processes the profile is getting overlapped and its openning the tests only in one browser.(This is happening only when run in parallel).
What could be missing in this?

Comment: Why are you trying to invoke `mvn -PChrome ..... test &` etc multiple times? Did you try to configure `testng.xml` to run parallel tests?

Comment: multiple time means

Comment: This is a job for a CI Solution like Jenkins using a pipeline where you can call chrome parallel to Firefox...